# How to read an IPv6 address, format in full expanded notation, then convert to binary?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ipv6

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

I'm trying to figure out how to read an IPv6 address stored as a string, then expand it into it's full 8 octet notation, and convert each octet into binary, and then add all the binary representations together to finally convert the address to binary.

The is the full notation:
2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
Short notation for same as it is stored in our database:
2001:0db8:85a3::8a2e:0370:7334

Here is an example of another valid IPv6 address:
::1

Wikpedia has the rules nicely laid out and explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_format

I'm not sure how to expand an IPv6 address to full notation and was hoping someone on here already has it figured out or knows how to do so. I googled this for hours but could not find any solution for SQL server 2005.

Once the address is expanded, I was thinking of splitting each octet based on the : and use the method outlined here to convert to binary: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83b70/4)

**Sample table**:

```
select '2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334' address
  into ipv6
  union all
select '2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:0370:7334' union all
select '2001:0db8:85a3::' union all
select '::ff01:0db8:85a3' union all
select '::1' union all
select '002::' union all
select '::' union all
select '1:2:3:4:5:6:7:' union all
select ':A:2:3:4:5:6:7' union all
select 'F:2:3:4:5:6::8' union all
select '' union all -- invalid
select null; -- null test
```

**Query**:

```
with step1(address,full8) as(
     select address,
            replace(nullif(address,''),'::',replicate(':',9-len(address)+len(replace(address,':',''))))
       from ipv6
), step2(address,full8,xml) as (
     select address, full8,
            cast('<x>'+replace(full8,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)
       from step1
), step3(address,full8,xml,part,pos) as (
     select address, full8,xml,
            right('0000'+part.value('.','varchar(4)'),4),
            part.value('for $s in . return count(../*[. << $s]) + 1', 'int') pos
       from step2
cross apply xml.nodes('x') node(part)
), step4(address,hex) as (
     select o.address, (select i.part+''
                          from step3 i
                         where i.address=o.address
                      order by i.pos
                           for xml path('')) hex
       from step3 o
group by address
)
     select address,
            hex,
            cast('' as xml).value(
              'xs:hexBinary(sql:column("hex"))','binary(16)') bin
       from step4
   order by address;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83b70/4/0)**:

```
|                                 ADDRESS |                              HEX |                                               BIN |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                      :: | 00000000000000000000000000000000 |                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |
|                                     ::1 | 00000000000000000000000000000001 |                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 |
|                        ::ff01:0db8:85a3 | 00000000000000000000ff010db885a3 |          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,13,-72,-123,-93 |
|                          :A:2:3:4:5:6:7 | 0000000A000200030004000500060007 |                  0,0,0,10,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7 |
|                                   002:: | 00020000000000000000000000000000 |                   0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |
|                          1:2:3:4:5:6:7: | 00010002000300040005000600070000 |                   0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,0 |
|                        2001:0db8:85a3:: | 20010db885a300000000000000000000 |          32,1,13,-72,-123,-93,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |
| 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334 | 20010db885a3000000008a2e03707334 | 32,1,13,-72,-123,-93,0,0,0,0,-118,46,3,112,115,52 |
|           2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:0370:7334 | 20010db885a3000000008a2e03707334 | 32,1,13,-72,-123,-93,0,0,0,0,-118,46,3,112,115,52 |
|                          F:2:3:4:5:6::8 | 000F0002000300040005000600000008 |                  0,15,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,0,0,8 |
```

*Note: SQL Fiddle doesn't display binary data very well...*

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Is there any way to rewrite this as an inline table valued function? I want to use it in a View query that is already quite complex and already has a CTE so I'm not sure how I would go about integrating the above CTE into what I have.